# Display HTML code with JS in GWT

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt

I want to create a page based on HTML code in GWT. This code has some js code
and its created from String object.
I create the HTML object in my widget:

```
  @UiField
  HTML htmlCont;
```

and put the String with HTML to content:

```
htmlCont.setHTML(htmlCode);
```

It generally works, but js code isn't interpreted and when i try put something
like this:

```
<p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>

<button onclick="clickFun()">Try it</button>

<script>
function clickFun() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
```

In my browser i get error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: clickFun is not defined

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add Javascript code with an `HTML` element, it's not going to be executable.

Use the [`ScriptInjector`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html) to add the Javascript:

```
String scriptBody = "var foo = ...";
ScriptInjector.fromString(scriptBody).inject();
```

---

Ideally you should create the widgets or elements yourself and use GWT methods to attach handlers to them or use [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Could you explain where I need to use ScriptInjector? Because when I used it in method where I set my html content it doesn't work... Before I tried to used native method from JSNI, but code could be different and could had more method than one.

Comment: @M.S. What's the reason for doing this in general anyway?

Comment: I want to test some html code with js (something like that: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2) and this code can often be different

Comment: @M.S. Is this for an actual product? If not, use jsni or simple HTML outside of a GWT application to test it.